# How can I trigger an event when a user clicks a GtkFileChooser or GtkFileChooserButton in GTK+3.0?

Tags: c++, gtk3, glade

I have a function that I'm using to grab properties of a widget when a user changes it's input for undo/redo functionality. I have entries connected such that when a user clicks on them (focus-in-event), the current text is taken and stored. However, I've been having a big problem trying to do this with a file chooser or file chooser button. For some reason, when I click the button or chooser, and I have my handler wired to the focus-in-event signal, the filename is not grabbed. I'm not sure how to grab this value before the user changes it. I'm using glade to attach handlers to signals. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by calling the `get_filename` method within a `selection-changed` callback. The `response` signal runs when the ok, or cancel button is clicked, and can be used to set or update which file/folder is selected to perform actions on.